# Set allow time in jQuery Ui Timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm using Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

```
jQuery('#element').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        timeFormat: "H:m",
        onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){

        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        }
    });
```

Now I want allow only 08:00 and 10:00 in timepicker, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to provided documentation you have to use 2 properties `minTIme` and `maxTime`. Smth like this:

```
<input type='text' class='timepicker' />

$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    minTime: '08:00',
    maxTime: '10:00',
    defaultTime: '9',
    startTime: '80:00',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});
```

===EDIT===

In this case I'd suggest you to create `change` handler for this timepicker and set it's value to default if wrong time was entered.

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
  interval: 60,
  minTime: '08:00',
  maxTime: '10:00',
  defaultTime: '9',
  startTime: '80:00',
  change: function(time) {
    debugger;
    if (time.getMinutes() !== 0) {
        alert('Wrong value');
            $('.timepicker').val('08:00');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It don't really work, because I still can choose 9:00 and 8:10 8:15 etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use options: `showmMinute: false` and `stepHour: 2`

https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

See code below:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
  interval: 60,
  minTime: '08:00',
  maxTime: '10:00',
  startTime: '8:00',
  showMinute: false,
  stepHour: 2
});
```

Added JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wvt2bnok/

Answer (score 0):

I used this library and it working fine with allowTimes option.
https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/